# Iframe doesn't resolves the value from controller after the first load

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I am using angular js frame work and has an iframe tag inside a ng-dialog. I am passing the src as

```
var SrcUrl=staticurl+dynamicUrl;
$scope.IframeSrcUrl=$sce.trustAsResourceUrl(SrcUrl);
```

and at the html

```
<iframe src="{{IframeSrcUrl}}" name="frame2" id="frame2" frameborder="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" scrolling="auto" onload="" allowtransparency="false" height="350px" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

The iframe will resolves the proper url on its initial load.. but once if i close the ng-dialog and again open it; it will consider the "IframeSrcUrl" as string take it as a param for my base url and will return a 404 error.
i have tried ng-src instead of src.. but it also didn't works..

here staticurl is an externally hosted site and dynamicUrl is a dynamic genarated parameter. whenever i do some action , for instance a button click i need to start the ng - dialog box which redirects to the IframeSrcUrl via iframe.
now the problem is that , on second load the iframe considers IframeSrcUrl as a string and try to redirect to 
"http://localhost:1337/%7B%7BIframeSrcUrl%7D%7D"

Comment: Is it inside a dialog box/

Comment: yes the iframe is inside the template of ng-dialog

Comment: It is hard to understand what is happening. Could you please give an example for what are the values? Or better: a way to reproduce your problem?

Comment: @TamasHegedus i will update the question

Comment: What did happen when you used ng-src?

Comment: ng-src didnt even render the IframeSrcUrl it shows as empty src

Answer (score 0):

On `load` event of the dialox box, try this :
`document.getElementById('frame2').src = document.getElementById('frame2').attr('data-src')` and put the attribute `data-src={{IframeSrcUrl}}` on your iframe.